# Does a family member of a Portuguese citizen need a visa to go on holiday to Spain?

Tags: visas, spain, eu

We are wanting to book a holiday to Spain.

My hubby holds a Portuguese passport, and I have a South African passport, but I do have a Family member EU residence permit/card.

Would I need to get a visa?

Comment: Where do you live?  What country issued the card?  When do you plan to travel?

Answer (score 2):

Your residence card that states that you are a "family member of an EU citizen" allows you to travel without a visa in the European Union and the Schengen area if you are accompanying or joining your husband.

If, however, your card was issued by the United Kingdom, and if the United Kingdom leaves the EU before your vacation begins, your card might not be recognized.  If your card is from the UK, it might be safer to get a visa to make sure you can travel even if the UK leaves the EU without a deal.